# Disable Commerce Card on File for Donation Product Type

Tags: 7, commerce

Using [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) (7.x-1.1), [Commerce Card on File](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cardonfile) (7.x-2.0-beta5), [Commerce Recurring Framework](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring) (7.x-2.x-dev) and [Commerce Donate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_donate) (7.x-1.0)

I need Commerce Card on File for my recurring product entities, however I do not want the functionality applied to Donation Products.

How do I keep the Commerce Card on File functionality for recurring products, but disable it for donation products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the Payment method configuration screen (admin/commerce/config/payment-methods), you'll see that each payment method is a rule. If you click on 'edit' you'll get a rules configuration screen.

[image]

Next, click on "Add condition" under the conditions section. Here you can choose the various conditions that allow (or disallow) a payment method to be selected.

[image: add condition]

You've got the order object here so you can choose 'Order contains a particular product'.

[image: order contains a particular product drop-down]

Then enter the SKU of your donation product in the field provided:

[image: Product sku entry text field]

Finally, make sure 'Negate' at the bottom of the rule configuration page is checked.

[image: Negate button on rules form]

Now that payment option will only show up if the order does not contain that product.

Comment: So basically, I will need to duplicate the rule, one for non-donation products and one for donation products.

Comment: If you have two different payment types you want to use, then yes.

Comment: I just have one, but I need one to have the card on file functionality, and one not to.